# Regex: Comma separated values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to make a regex that will: match only if all condition are met, will not match 1 to 10 or something like it and will ignore commas.

I have made `(?=.*1)(?=.*5)` which almost works and will match to `1,5` as it is meant to but will also match to `10,5`,`10,50` and `1,50`. I can not work out how to stop this. So my question is how do I get the regex to know the difference between numerals and a single digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it match word boundaries around the number, using `\b`.

```
(?=.*\b1\b)(?=.*\b5\b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this has been a problem I have been trying to get for hours. Thank you